# How to set fixed no. of ticks on axis in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display data in bar graph, in which there is need to show the max value possible in a category. However when using tick() method of d3.js it automatically adjust the ticks to the max value in the data set.

Desired x-axis ticks :

c1 -----------> 5

c2 ------> 3

---

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

Comment: Use [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues).

Answer (score 5):

Axis ticks can be specified using [ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks)

```js
var data = [{"closePriceDate":"Apr-8-2016","closePrice":93.24},{"closePriceDate":"Apr-9-2016","closePrice":95.35}];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b-%e-%Y");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.closePriceDate); }))
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
 .ticks(4) //specify number of ticks 
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it seems to be working quite odd in v4. I set ticks to (9) and I see 12 rendered ticks. I set it to (6) and I see 7 rendered :/

Comment: @vsync Docs on .ticks say: "The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain."

If you want further customization, use tickValues as Lars said. But then you have to give in the values yourself...

Comment: it only works for specific numbers like 4 6 12. How to have 5 ticks or 7 ticks?